# Output of System command in perl

Tags: perl

I have the following command

```
system("ssh $host_name sh /tmp/a.sh $file_name $region $domain < /tmp/info.txt > $resFile ");
```

However, this command is not working as expected. Please suggest how to get the failure reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working as expected"? Does it not produce the output you expect? Does it fail with some error? Does it set your computer on fire?

Comment: $resFile is getting created , but with no contents. The same a.sh script, when I run directly from the host, it is creating the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to see the error messages produced by the system call, I'd recommend concatenating both `stdout` and `stderr` and redirecting them by placing `2>&1` at the end of the call:

```
system("ssh $host_name sh /tmp/a.sh $file_name $region $domain < /tmp/info.txt > $resFile 2>&1 ");`
```

Then, anything in `stderr` will also be printed in `$resfile`, and you can inspect the errors to try and discover what went wrong.

Comment: ok, let me give it a try

Comment: Thanks a lot , That helped in identifying the issue.

Comment: You can post an answer if you have identified the problem yourself.